# Display A TTStyledTextLabel in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, ttstyledtextlabel

How can I set a TTStyledTextLabel inside of a UITableView.
Each TTStyledTextLabel contains Some parsed HTML.

Heres what I have I realize its probably completely wrong.

```
TTStyledTextLabel* label = [[TTStyledTextLabel alloc] autorelease];
cell.textLabel.text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:tempString lineBreaks:YES URLs:YES];
```

App Crashes on launch. I think its because I am setting the .text property with something that is not text. However, I don't know what else to set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will do what you want. Unfortunately, however, I cannot figure out how to automatically set the height. If memory isn't an issue you could keep a seperate array of TTStyledTextLabels and reference their heights.

in your loadView:

```
CGRect cgRct2 = CGRectMake(0, 35, 320, 375); //define size and position of view 
    tblView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:cgRct2 style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tblView.dataSource = [self constructDataSource];
    tblView.delegate = self;
    //[tblView reloadData];
    [myView addSubview:tblView];
```

in your class:

```
-(TTListDataSource *)constructDataSource {
    NSLog(@"constructDataSource");
    NSMutableArray * namesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //ADD ITEMS
    [namesArray addObject:[TTStyledText textFromXHTML:[NSString stringWithString:@"some XHTML"]]];




    TTListDataSource * dataSource = [[TTListDataSource alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < [namesArray count]; i++) {
        TTStyledText * text = [namesArray objectAtIndex:i];

        [dataSource.items addObject:[TTTableStyledTextItem itemWithText:text]];
    }

    [namesArray release];
    return dataSource;
}
```